# Правильная пунктуация?

Tags: пунктуация

**Даже когда звук песни прекратился и воцарилась тишина, некоторые продолжали танец и платочки взлетали тут и там.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильная; одно место в предложении требует к ответу автора (без него никак).

> Даже когда звук песни прекратился и воцарилась тишина, некоторые
>   продолжали танец и платочки взлетали тут и там.

Перед "и платочки взлетали тут и там" возможна запятая, если полёт платочков никак не связан с воцарением тишины, а связан или нет, на то авторская воля (ему видней, что там по сюжету происходит).

Правило: общее придаточное отменяет запятую между двумя простыми предложениями, входящими в состав главного.

Comment: А общее главное отменяет запятую между двумя придаточными, так? Поэтому и после *прекратился* запятой нет?

Comment: Фу ты. У них общее - "даже когда", что отменяет запятую.

Comment: Пардон... на старуху проруха )

Comment: Ета кто у нас старуха с прорухой, м?! О_о

Answer (score 3):

Даже когда звук песни прекратился и воцарилась тишина, некоторые продолжали танец, и платочки взлетали тут и там.

**Я бы поставила запятую**, так как последнее предложение является следствием по отношению к предыдущему содержанию, **нет тесной связи двух последних предложений.**

Сравнить у Розенталя: [§ 30. Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

Как только сапёры перетащили машину на другую сторону и поставили на шоссе, Зубенко дал газ, и грузовик преспокойно поехал дальше (Медв.) — последнее предложение указывает на общее следствие.

В устной речи **наличие паузы** также желательно.